# Switch between different API hosts

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, block, afnetworking

I'm working on an app which primarily works with an API that will be installed in an internal system. The API is also accessible via the public internet. The client wants to allow users to enter both an internal and external (public internet) URL that the app will then connect to depending on availability of the internal and external URLs.

The app is basically done with the exception that it currently connects to the internal URL only for all it's API calls. I'm using AFNetworking with block-based completion/failure invocations for each API call.

Based on the logic that we have designed, the app will always check for the API's availability by querying for the server's current time. This is done by calling `http://internal_url/api/time`. If this API fails to return an appropriate respond, we'll switch to the external URL `http://external_url/api/time` and call the same API on that URL. If both fails, the app will inform the user accordingly and not perform any other queries to the API.

Without revealing too much, here's some code on how I the API calls are currently setup:

```
- (void)someAPIMethodCall:(NSDictionary *)parameters completionBlock:block failure:block {
// query /api/time and return the URL (internal/external) that is currently up

AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:<url returned from above query>];
[client operationWithSuccess:block failure:block];
}
```

So my question would be: what is the best way to get the query `/api/time` method above to work? Obviously, this method needs to complete and return either the internal/external URL so that the subsequent actual API query could use. AFAIK, AFNetworking calls are block-based so it will return before the above `/api/time` returns. I've also thought of a separate class that uses NSURLConnection synchronously which will block the main-thread while it waits for the `/api/time` to return.

Comment: Once you determine `internal_url` vs. `external_url`, does that ever change during the lifetime of the app?

Comment: @AaronBrager Since it is preferable that we connect to the API which is hosted internally, our logic is to check the system time and switch back to using `internal_url` at the dot of the hour. P/S: I didn't come up with this logic, the client did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to tell you to simply use the same URL internally and externally (via DNS) but that's not what you want.

I think you're asking how to conditionally call the other url.

You want someAPIMethodCall to be asynchronous... so you don't want to block on the call to checking for the correct api to call.

Aside from caching the results so you don't have to do this every time, you simply want to call another block based method of your own that has a completion block which passes IN a parameter of the URL to call for your real query.

```
- (void)someAPIMethodCall:(NSDictionary *)parameters completionBlock:(void (^)(void))succesBlock failure((^)(void)):failureBlock {
    [self callBlockWithMyApiUrl:^(NSString *apiUrl){
        AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:apiUrl];
        [client operationWithSuccess:successBlock failure:failureBlock];
    } onFailure:^{
        failureBlock
    }
}

- (NSString *)callBlockWithMyApiUrl:(NSString * (^)(void))success (void (^)(void))failure
{
    // Your code to test for the working URI
    // If you're doing it this way, I'd suggest caching the result.
    // Subscribe to networking interface changes to dump the cache.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I followed this method and am currently having success implementing it.